# Xapian vs Lucene.Net - Arabic documents text search

Tags: c#, full-text-search, lucene.net, arabic, xapian

i am facing the problem of text search through a large amount of Arabic content documents (PDF and Doc files) in C# .Net.

after a lot and a lot searching, i came up with 2 solutions,

**First, Lucene.Net** and i faced the following issues

1- Arabic analyzer to be used with Lucene.Net and found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-392), don know yet if it will be working !

2- Extracting the text from the documents (about 6000 PDF and Doc files) and found Tika which i will be using in .Net with the help of ikvm.
However, given that this solution will work, i don know the performance will be.

**Second, Xapian** and i moved to this solution in-order to make use of omega library, but still found some issues

1- Will xapian work with Arabic context or it will be needing an Arabic analyzer too and if so how will i work this problem around

indeed, i cant decide which solution to go with regarding Arabic content and an almost large amount of data.

Any help or suggestion is very appreciated,

Thanks,

Samer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nLucene you have to create arabic analyzer, but Im using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and its working fine with Arabic language. Check [this topic](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Arabic)

Comment: so can Solr do the 3 step, extracting text then indexing then searching ?